# I can not see the text of checkboxes inside scrollView

Tags: android, checkbox, scrollview

I have been stuck for several hours in that problem.

When I run the code i see the checkboxes inside the scrollView but I can not see their description text.

For example I need something like that

[image]

In my app I can only see the checkboxes and nothing more.

My xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearStoScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Sunday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Sunday" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Monday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Monday" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Tuesday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Tuesday" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Wednesday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Wednesday" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Thursday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Thursday" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Friday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Friday" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/Saturday"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Saturday" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/myScrollLayout">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ok_button_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick=""
            android:text="OK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick=""
            android:text="Cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you
/mkounal

Comment: can you post your screenshot..how its coming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default the text color in android is **black**. And you have added layout *Backcolor* as black too. So how could it be visible.?

Please change text color of *Checkboxes* to white by

```
android:textColor = "#FFFFFF"
```